# Kubernetes pods are not getting distributed after uncordon the worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I have 1 master, 2 worker node kubernetes cluster, I have drained one worker node to apply os patch and to reboot. after the reboot I have uncordoned the worker node in master, when I checked the pod distribution under particular namespace , I could see all the pods are running on one server( not distributed with other node). Then I restarted the deployments expecting a redistribution but then all the pods under particular namespace transfers to the other node. How can I redistribute the pods as they were initially distributed.
Should I really drain/uncordon servers when performing server restarts?